# How to perform ANOVA on response variable with indicator variable?

Tags: r, anova, self-study

I have a data that looks like this

```
   City Sex Rater  drink response

1    NY   M     1   coke       77

2    NY   M     2   coke       72

3    NY   F     3   coke       78

...
```

There are 3 different cities and 3 different types of drinks, and n=48.

How should I do ANOVA on this?

Here's the data.

```
structure(list(City = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("LA", "NY"), class = "factor"), 
    Sex = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), 
    Rater = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), chip = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("coke", 
    "pepsi", "sprite"), class = "factor"), response = c(77L, 72L, 
    78L, 84L, 77L, 78L, 83L, 81L, 76L, 71L, 78L, 84L, 76L, 77L, 
    86L, 84L, 78L, 73L, 78L, 84L, 74L, 81L, 85L, 83L, 80L, 75L, 
    80L, 86L, 72L, 73L, 81L, 79L, 78L, 76L, 84L, 90L, 78L, 79L, 
    88L, 86L, 81L, 73L, 81L, 87L, 81L, 82L, 92L, 90L)), .Names = c("City", 
"Sex", "Rater", "drink", "response"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-48L))
```

Comment: This overly broad question could be greatly improved by performing preliminary research and being more specific about what kind of model is under consideration.

Comment: Is this related to your [preceding question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19954/computing-anova-in-r)?

Comment: What is `rater` ?

Comment: I agree with whuber. What's your _question_? How to do anova on this data-set is too broad. There's plenty of resources on how to do anova in R, just flip through some pages here on CV, the search function is pretty powerful.

Answer (score 2):

What do you think of this?

```
> lm(response ~ City+Sex+Rater+drink, data=x) -> model
> model

Call:
lm(formula = response ~ City + Sex + Rater + drink, data = x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)       CityNY         SexM        Rater   drinkpepsi  drinksprite    
  8.150e+01   -7.500e-01   -6.750e+00    2.500e-01   -4.668e-15    4.000e+00  

> anova(model)
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: response
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
City       1  36.75   36.75  4.0726 0.0500025 .  
Sex        1 630.75  630.75 69.8984 1.766e-10 ***
Rater      1   0.75    0.75  0.0831 0.7745397    
drink      2 170.67   85.33  9.4565 0.0004068 ***
Residuals 42 379.00    9.02                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Note that there are only two cities in the data set you give, NY and LA. If you can describe the data, it can help to comment a little more...

Comment: Please note our policy about responses to homework questions in the [FAQ](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq).  (This one almost surely is homework, even though it was not originally tagged as such.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SPSS, then use the GLM under the "Analyse" tab. GLM allows you to see the main effects and the interaction of your predictor variables on your response variable.

Answer (score 0):

I guess 2 way ANOVA should do the needful. And don't worry about normality much, because ANOVA is robust w.r.to non-normality.